# python qgis 2.4 : display a view with symbology

Tags: qgis, postgresql, symbology

I have managed to display a view created using postgresql from qgis using python code:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "stat", "postgres", "admin")
uri.setDataSource("public", "view2", "the_geom", ' ', "gid")
uri.uri()
qgis.utils.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "allcountries", "postgres")
```

Now I want to display this view with symbology (classes), I searched a lot but it was not clear.
For example: I tried to do it with:

```
myVectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer("polygon", "mypoly", 'ogr')
myTargetField = 'code'
myRangeList = []
myOpacity = 1
# Make our first symbol and range...
myMin = 0.0
myMax = 50.0
myLabel = 'Group 1'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#ffee00')
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol1.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol1.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange1 = QgsRendererRangeV2(myMin, myMax, mySymbol1, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange1)
#now make another symbol and range...
myMin = 50.1
myMax = 100
myLabel = 'Group 2'
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#00eeff')
mySymbol2 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol2.setColor(myColour)
mySymbol2.setAlpha(myOpacity)
myRange2 = QgsRendererRangeV2(myMin, myMax, mySymbol2, myLabel)
myRangeList.append(myRange2)
myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2('', myRangeList)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval)
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(myTargetField)

myVectorLayer.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(myVectorLayer)
```

This gives me an error:

> mySymbol1.setColor(myColour) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setColor'

Answer (score 1):

```
myVectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer("polygon", "mypoly", 'ogr')
```

does not create a valid vector layer, therefore

```
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
```

does not return a valid symbol and causes the error you see.

Replace `"polygon"` with a valid file path.

Comment: we must put the type of geometry (polygon), is that true? on which file path you speak ? i don't understand. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, thanks to @Underdark.

The error was in the instruction qgsVectorLaye:

```
myVectorLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "allcountries", 'postgres')
```